# How can I print \twonotes from wasysym?

Tags: fonts, symbols, pdftex

When I try to compile the following example with pdftex, I get:

```
pdflatex symbol.tex -output-format=pdf
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./symbol.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/wasysym.sty)
No file symbol.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/uwasy.fd) [1{/usr/local/t
exlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./symbol.aux) )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file wasy10.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for rea
ding
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'make' failed
make: *** [make] Error 1
```

The relevant line seems to be

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file wasy10.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading

[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/uwasy.fd) [1{/usr/local
/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./symbol.aux) )</
usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file wasy10.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for rea
ding
```

However, the `was10.pfb` exists and has `-rw-r--r--` as rights which should be enough.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

### Minimal Example

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}\twonotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just in case somebody wonders why I need this: I've just introduced tags to write-math.com. One tag I just created is [`music`](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/tags/music).

Comment: That a file exists doesn't imply that pdflatex can find it. What do you get with `kpsewhich wasy10.pfb`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer When I execute that command, it returns nothing. What does that mean? How can I tell LaTeX where it is? (and why can't pdflatex find it when it does report the file to the log?

Comment: Where is the pfb?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb` (it does exist, checked with `ls`)

Comment: cmr10.pfb is not wasy10.pfb

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I'm sorry. `wasy10.pfb` is at `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/wasy2-ps/wasy10.pfb`

Comment: Did you run texhash?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Great! That made it work! Could you please explain why this is the case?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- i think in this case, the solution deserves an answer.  texhash is pretty much expected for macro packages, but it's not necessarily an automatic reflex for fonts.

Comment: I have no idea why texhash was necessary -- the font should have been installed along with the other files (e.g. the .fd) and so found like the other files. But as kpsewhich didn't found it, it was obvious that the ls-R was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: The problem was solved by running `texhash` so that the library `kpse` could find the font.  Why this was necessary is not clear, a standard installation should have stored this information already.